# allow redeploy of the same pom file

Tags: ant, ivy, nexus

We have a project where I upload the artifacts to a `nexus` repository using `ant` and `ivy`. Things have gone smooth for a long time, but now we must deploy the same artifact twice (because we are generating the same product for windows and mac). The code of the application is the same, it just changes the packaging. I have configured the deploy process to use a maven classifier. The problem is that the uploads are done from 2 different machines because each one has the appropiate build environment for the destination platform.

So, the first deploy is done right and it uploads:

- myproduct-1.0.pom
- myproduct-1.0-mac.zip

When I try to deploy the windows artifact, that will deploy

- myproduct-1.0.pom
- myproduct-1.0-win32.msi

It fails because the repository policy does not allow redeploying (and it should stay that way), so trying to deploy a new pom file for the same artifact and version fails, even if the pom contents are the same.

Also it is possible that in the future we have a similar problem, deploying various artifacts of the same product and version but different classifier from the different machine but in different build processes.

Is it possible to tell nexus to not fail if when deploying a classified artifact with a pom, does not fail if the same pom file already exists in the repository? If it is not possible, I understand that the only way to deploy various artifacts with different classifiers is to deploy them all at the same time. Is it true?

Comment: Does a single run of "mvn package" generate both the windows and the mac packages?  If so, you can use the build-helper-maven-plugin to attach-artifacts and have all of them deploy at once w/o the issue you're talking about.

Comment: @Michael no, they are generated at different times in different computers

Comment: Then you'll need to go w/ your answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I created a task that deployed just the pom without any classifier, and modified the deploy of the windows & mac artifacts to just deploy the packages but not the pom:

1. deploy pom without classifier
2. deploy mac artifact with classifier (mac)
3. deploy win artficat with classifier (win32)

Nexus doesn't complain when deploying the artifact without deploying a pom file at the same time when I thought I would complain.

I feel it's a dirty trick, but it works :)